# Workflow to be run for every specific document or content type?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, document-library, powershell-script

I will need to look for the solution to implement the manual script initiation for specific file type in the document library (ex. force unlocking a document). Idea is that I will add additional column with the link to manually trigger a workflow to every item with appropriate content type (only MS Office file types). It should look like this:

User click on the link of workflow of specific document --> Workflow (param documentId) --> execute the script on the server (with documentId param).

Is that scenario possible, if not with workflows, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

By design, SharePoint Workflow cannot call a customized powershell script. On the other hand, you can start SharePoint Workflows through PowerShell commands.

You could refer to this case:

- [SP2013 Workflow to invoke Powershell](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/458819-sp2013-workflow-to-invoke-powershell)